# Script tag's local variable is not working in EJS tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
HTML:

<% for (let i = 0; i < monthlyTopSellers.imageUrlList.length; i++){ %>

<button id="test<%= i+1 %>">Buy Now</button>

<% } %>

<script>
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        $('#test'+i.toString()).click(function () {
            let item = <%= items[i] %>
            // Then I just will use item variable
        }
    }
</script>
```

It gives me an error saying 'i' is not defined, at this code 'let item = <%= items[i] %>'. Is there any solution or some other method to solve the issue.

Comment: Because the loop in script tag runs client side, not server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejs don't run loop `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)` (client), it is just run with loop inside your `<%  %>`

You can create `itemsClient` with `items` before `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

and use `itemsClient` inside that loop.

```
<% for (let i = 0; i < monthlyTopSellers.imageUrlList.length; i++){ %>

<button id="test<%= i+1 %>">Buy Now</button>

<% } %>

<script>
let itemsClient = <%- JSON.stringify(items) %>;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    $('#test'+i.toString()).click(function () {
        let item = itemsClient[i];
        // Use item (itemsClient[i])
    }
}
</script>
```

You can test it.

Comment: Can you provide the edited code in your answer, please?

Comment: I edited it, I don't sure it work, but if not, just edit something

Comment: Can you explain please, what "myVar" is? I did not pass it from the server.

Comment: Sorry, it is `items`, your variable send to client

Comment: Giving error again, on the same line, i.e let itemsClient = <%- JSON.stringify(items) %>;

Comment: Can you upload error, and what is `items` (array, object, )

Answer (score -1):

At first, you should pass the i count array from node.js to ejs as json object.
Then you get that variable in ejs.
And you can use this foreach statement for your ejs.

```
<% monthlyTopSellers.imageUrlList.forEach(function(imgurl, index){ %>
    <button id="test<%=index %>">Buy Now</button>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: I cannot pass i variable from node server. I want to create and use it in the client side.